# What measures should I take before inserting one million records to database at one time?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a java code that parses a website's content and inserts each row of the html table to my oracle database. Website has around 70000 pages that I want to parse and each page has a very simple URL to loop through, such as this:

```
http://website.com/contents?id=1
```

So when I change the Id to 2 it basically goes to the next page. And each page has 14-15 row html tables on average.

I also create a log (via java.util.logging.Logger) file to see if there is something wrong with the insertion.

I tried until page Id 10 (around 150 records), and it worked without problems, but didn't tried for the 70000 pages (1.000.000 records) yet. I am doing this on my home computer and with oracle express edition. What should I consider before I try to insert 1.000.000 records at one go?

Comment: You should consider testing it and seeing what happens.  Almost certainly it will do something no-one can predict for you use case.

Comment: The bottleneck will not the insert operation into Oracle DB but receiving and parsing the HTML page.

Comment: On the Oracle side, you should definitely make sure Oracle commits it's changes every 10000 rows or so, trying to insert all rows in one transaction will most likely flood your SGA and rollback the transaction.

Comment: Inserting a million rows is hardly a lot. Jut do it. Any decent hardware should be able to cope with that. Do **not** commit every 10000 rows. Commit **once** at the end. Frequent commits make Oracle _slower_ not faster.

Comment: @YaronIdan: that's a bad advice. [To quote Tom Lane](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4951966319022) "*it slows you down, yes, that is right, SLOWS YOU DOWN -- makes you run SLOOOWWWWEEERRR, doesn't conserve any resources, in fact, it consumes more (you generate MORE redo)*"

Comment: I agree most servers should be able to handle a 1000000 row insert easily, but since this query is intended to run on a home computer I thought this would be the safest way to avoid rolling back the entire query in case the user's RAM resources are scarce. I think the most interesting way to settle this is for OP to run the query with no commits in the middle and let us know if the query completed successfully.

Comment: @YaronIdan -- My two cents' worth - it wasn't lines on web site pages, it was numbers in a "generate 100,000 permutations of the numbers 1,...,50" - but still, it was 5 million rows. Inserted all at once, in a few seconds, on my cheap laptop - with the free XE edition of Oracle, the only one I have. Absolutely no problems; commit at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First , Oracle XE edition has size limitations. If inserts exceeded that size , you will not possible to add rows.

For large number of inserts for several sessions , you can increase table `FREELISTS`size. If `REDO` generation is not necessary, you can use `APPEND` hint.

If your application can do, you can export data in a flat file then run Sql*Loader to import all data once into the table. You can do this programmatically.